# Constructing a dictionary with multi part keys

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to create a dictionary dict with the key having two parts k1 and k2. k1 is the actual key and k2 is the length of dict[k1, k2]. In the below example, k1 is 'cat' and k2 is 10. k2 is just the size of the list of values and does not contribute towards the uniqueness of key.

```
dict = {
        cat, 10: [value1, value2, value3, ..., value10],
        dog, 15: [value1, value2, value3, ..., value15],
        zen, 15: [value1, value2, value3, ..., value15]
       }
```

What I did was, implemented the dict without k2, and then concatenated k1 and k2, which means the key is actually k1k2, leading to the following implementation.

```
if key not in dict:
  dict[key] = [value1]
else:
  if value_n not in dict[key]:
    dict[key].append(value_n)

for key in dict:
  key = key + str(len(dict[key]))
```

Now the dict appears like this.

```
dict = {
        cat10: [value1, value2, value3, ..., value10],
        dog15: [value1, value2, value3, ..., value15],
        zen15: [value1, value2, value3, ..., value15]
       }
```

As I don't want to store k2 in a separate data structure, how can I implement multi part keys in a dictionary?

Comment: Have you tried using a tuple? eg: `('cat', 10): [value1..., value15]` ?

Comment: why do you want to store len at a given time when you can just use the  len (dict[cat]) which will return 10

Comment: @Jon: I am not aware of a tuple. Thanks for the comment. Let me look into that.

Comment: @Rohit: k2 is in fact a value derived interatively as value list is filled. I took k2 as a length here to keep the problem simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure exactly what your use-case here is. But it seems to me that you can do one of of a few options. And that depends on if the "length" key (k2) is what creates the list, or is just an indicator of it.

---

You could use nested dictionaries:

```
dict = {
        'cat' : {10: [value1, value2, value3, ..., value10]},
        'dog' : {15: [value1, value2, value3, ..., value15]},
        'zen' : {15: [value1, value2, value3, ..., value15]}
       }
```

So that access would be `dict['cat'][10]` and this would work if the "length" (k2) is simply an indicator of the length.

---

You could create a custom class which will let you access "keys" and specify the length you want the value to be. The method in the class would be something *like*:

```
def method(self, key, length):
    return self.__dict__[key][:length]
```

---

You could use a tuple as your key:

```
dict = {
        ('cat', 10) : [value1, value2, value3, ..., value10],
        ('dog', 15) : [value1, value2, value3, ..., value15],
        ('zen', 15) : [value1, value2, value3, ..., value15]
       }
```

Comment: I can see one thing in the nested dict. later in the program if the user wants to add or delete something (e.g in cat value 11) then the dict will be having both 10 and 11 in the cat dict

Comment: @RohitSrivastava I am sorry, your comment makes no sense to me. Could you please try again? Or perhaps you could illustrate your example in code and link a http://pastebin.com/ to it?

Comment: OP has a purpose to add the length of it. Suppose I want to add a value 11 in the cat:{10: [value1,....,value 10]}. If I add that and use the same then it may become  cat:{10:[value1,....,value10], 11:[value1,....,value11] or anything else, there may be some other cases depending upon the implementation. OP needs to take care of those things.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class with `__eq__` and `__hash__` implemented. Then you can use instances of that class as dictionary keys:

```
class MyKey(object):
    def __init__(self, animal, length):
        self.__animal = animal
        self.length = length

    @property
    def animal(self):
        return self.__animal

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.__animal)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__animal == other.animal

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{0}({1}, {2})".format(
            self.__class__.__name__, self.animal, self.length)
```

I hope I've understood you correctly in that you want to use only the animal as key, and just *bundle* the length with it witout having it affect the uniqueness of the key.

As you see I've made the animal a read-only property and name-mangled the underlying attribute, both to prevent you from accidently altering that attribute. If you do that to an instance you use as a dict key, bad things<sup>TM</sup> will happen.

Note that since the dict sees `MyKey("ox", 9)` as the same key as `MyKey("ox", 3)`, the behaviour of code like this is unspecified, as far as I know:

```
d = {}
d[MyKey("ox", 9)] = "a"
d[MyKey("ox", 3)] = "b"
assert len(d) == 1
# will the key have value 9 or 3? I wouldn't depend on it always being the same.
print d.keys()
```

So now you can have code like this:

```
key = MyKey(animal, 0)
if key not in mydict:
    mydict[key] = [value1]
else:
    if value_n not in mydict[key]:
        dict[key].append(value_n)

for key, value in mydict.items():
    key.length = len(value)
```

All that being said, you're *probably* better off solving this problem in another way. Why can't you call `len(value)` directly when you need the lenght? That is a very fast operation (in fact, it just reads a pre-calculated variable of the underlying python object.)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. To your question at the end, k2 is in fact a value derived interatively as value list is filled. I took k2 as a length here to keep the problem simple.